# How can I trap the unknown cause of a Javascript popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, firebug, breakpoints

I am debugging someone else's web page. There is a link on it which tries to open itself in a popup window, the reason for this is unclear -- there is nothing obvious in the HTML (onclick=foo) to cause this.

Disabling JavaScript means the link opens normally. I have Firefox/Firebug/Dom Inspector and would like to trap whatever JavaScript event is leading to the popup. Since I can't find the code, I'm stuck.

Can Firebug create a sort of global breakpoint to trap all code? Is there some other way to hook into this behaviour and inspect it?

The page in question is http://hijinxmusic.co.uk/ and the problem link is "Green Policy" near the bottom.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The green policy document opens a popup with itself on load:

```
<body onload="MM_openBrWindow('green%20policy.htm','green','width=900,height=600')">
```

This is *inside* `green policy.htm`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963457/how-can-i-trap-the-unknown-cause-of-a-javascript-popup/1963462#1963462), the function that gets executed on body load in the page at `http://hijinxmusic.co.uk/green%20policy.htm`  essentially calls `window.open()`

```
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
    window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bigger problem is that the page that you are trying to open in a new window is the same window that the user is already looking at, which doesn't make any sense.  What's more is that if the popup blocker wasn't blocking window creation, you would have an infinite loop of popups (load `green policy.html`, open a new `green policy.html`, load `green policy.html`, etc).  Where did you want the popup to happen?

Also, to add to [Russ Cam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963457/how-can-i-trap-the-unknown-cause-of-a-javascript-popup/1963634#1963634), you can detect when the popup fails to open by checking the return value of `window.open`.  I have used this successfully in Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari (haven't needed to test in Chrome).  Using the provided function, this is how I handle blocked popups:

```
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
    if ( !window.open(theURL, winName, features) ) {
        // Window failed to open:
        // show a HTML dialog/popover that prompts the user to allow
        // popups from this site, along with a `cancel` and `try again`
        // button.  The `try again` button will attempt to open the
        // window again with the provided parameters
        dialog.popupBlockedNotice.open(arguments);
    }
    // Window opened successfully.
}
```